# How to set search path dynamically in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could anyone help me to update search path dynamically in PostgreSQL without change in conf files? because I don't want to restart my Postgres service once my application is up.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [SET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html) command to issue, for example:

```
 SET search_path TO myschema,public;
```

Alternatively you can use

```
 ALTER ROLE your_db_user SET search_path TO ....;
```

so you won't have to execute the `SET` on each connection.

Comment: You can also `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...` to set it for all users on a given database.